# How to remove margin on horizontal list line break?

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

I have a top navigation bar which I want to be always visible even when the screen is only 320px wide. Here is what I have done:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
  <li>Products</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Videos</li>
  <li>News</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

I display the list horizontally using this CSS:

```
nav li { float: left; }
nav li + li { margin-left: 30px; }
```

I end up with this:

```
Products   Services    Videos    News    Contact
```

This is fine until the screen becomes small and the final two list items get pushed down to the next row like this:

```
Products   Services    Videos    
      News    Contact
```

I need to remove the left margin of the first item that is on a new row like this:

```
Products   Services    Videos    
News    Contact
```

How could this be achieved? I don't mind changing my HTML and CSS completely to achieve it - as long as it can be done!

Comment: CSS cannot detect when an item is wrapped in a new line (yet).

Comment: You could add a class to the last two li and have a media query that resets the margin on only that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply apply a **right** margin instead of left margin. That way when items are broken into a new line, there will not be a space before them:

```css
nav li { float: left; margin-right: 30px; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
  <li>Products</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Videos</li>
  <li>News</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

[image: css menu margin]

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/v1f9hL04/

Comment: Perfect and simple! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Swap it and use `margin-right` instead

```css
nav li { float: left; }
nav li:not(:last-child) { margin-right: 30px; }

nav { width: 250px; }  /* just to show the effect of a line break */
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
  <li>Products</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Videos</li>
  <li>News</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Another option, which can become useful, is adding equal margin on both sides of each item.

Then, if the layout allows it, one can give the parent an equal negative margin, or just leave it, and you'll end up with the same result, all left aligned when line breaks

```css
nav li { float: left }
nav li { margin: 0 15px }

nav ~ nav { margin-left: -15px }

nav { width: 250px; }  /* just to show the effect of a line break */
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
  <li>Products</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Videos</li>
  <li>News</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
 </ul>
</nav>

<br><br><br>
<nav>
  <ul>
  <li>Products</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Videos</li>
  <li>News</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This works perfectly as well as Aziz's solution. I like that this has the not:(:last-child) psuedo selector. I would have voted as answer but Aziz was a little quicker so I thought it would be fair to give him the green tick. Thank you so much

Comment: @volumeone Thanks, I also updated with a 2:nd approach. May I suggest, for the future, you accept the answer you used, not the fastest, though in this case we kind of posted the same so _the fastest is okay_ :)